# R - pass a global variable to a function, modify it and save

Tags: r, eval

I'm trying to build a dynamic function utilizing eval,parse, or whatever works

Intention of a function: a value setter.

Parameter input: list, name of list item, value

Return: don't really care

Current code

```
#call fun_lsSetValue(state_list,selected,"dropdown")

fun_lsSetValue <- function(ls,name,value){
 pars <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
 element <- as.character(eval(expression(pars$name)))
 if(is.null(value))
  eval(parse(text="ls[[element]] <- ''"))
 else
  eval(parse(text="ls[[element]] <- value"))

#part that I need help, I need to assign ls to "state_list" without 
#having to hard coded it in this function
#I have tried everything I can think of like
#assign(deparse(substitute(ls)),ls,.GlobalEnv)
#state_list <<- ls works, but I want to be dynamic
}
```

The problem I found is I need to pass the value of a local variable "ls" to where it came from dynamically (state_list)
I know a <- function(a,name,value) {... return(a)} work, but this syntax is really not my preference.
Since I'm trying to learn if same thing can be done without the assign out side of function. 
Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: The prologue to this question is ... just wrong. In R the strategy is to return a value , not to "set" a value. There is a function, `<<-` that is probably doing better than you are coding but it is deprecated for regular use. Maybe you want a different language?

Comment: Stop torturing part of the language to make it do something it wasn't designed to do. Use one of R's actual OOP systems like S4, reference classes, proto, R6, etc.

Comment: Take a step back- tell us what your larger code is doing. We can probably help you to do what you are attempting in a way that will make you much happier in the long run.

Comment: I want to have a function that is able to take global list name, index name, value. If the value does not exist / not provided for that name, assign "" to it to prevent error in down stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is a terrible idea in general, something like

```
fun_lsSetValue <- function(ls,name,value){
    lsname <- deparse(substitute(ls))
    name <- deparse(substitute(name))
    ls <- get(lsname, envir=globalenv())
    if(is.null(value)) {
        value<-''
    }
    ls[[name]]<-value
    assign(lsname, ls,envir=globalenv())
}
```

should work

```
a <- list(x=1)
fun_lsSetValue(a,x,3)
a
# $x
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. What will be the best practice for such scenario then?

Comment: It depends on why you think this type of function is necessary. Are you trying to simulate object-oriented programming? Are you trying to automate something? This is just not the way anyone at all familiar with R would expect things to be done so it would create a nightmare for maintenance and debugging.